# Передача данных из формы между компонентами Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Есть форма она разделена на 2 компонента ,один компонент отвечает за input-ы ,второй отвечает за отображение popup-а на котором должны будут отображенные те данные которые были введены ранее в input-ах ,типа некой проверки перед отправкой ,вопрос состоит в том что каким образом передавать данные между этими компонентами грубо говоря в реальном времени

Comment: если popup является, дочерним по отношению к форме, то через props, если нет, то через Vuex или event-bus

Comment: Благодарю буду ,пробовать